# How to validate in database for uniqueness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5.

Here is my API table:

```
create_table "apis", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "status"
  t.string   "coname"
end
```

How do I validate that a user cannot create an API with the same name and same status twice?

For example, (name)"ABC" with (status) "good" already exist and next time you cannot not create it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put this validation into you Api model:

`validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :status, message: 'your custom message' }`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: And "*It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database, so it may happen that two different database connections create two records with the same value for a column that you intend to be unique. To avoid that, you must create a unique index on both columns in your database.*"

Comment: One more question, how do I set different message for this validates?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a unique index in the database and/or a uniqueness validation in the rails model class.

The unique index would be set up in a migration, like this:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToApis < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_index :apis, [:name, :status], unique: true
end
```

And the validation would be something like this:

```
class Api < ActiveRecord::Model
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :status }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that in both `model` and `migration`file. I will suggest you to do this in both places but only model/migration will work too.

> Note that applying restriction inside the model will provide you
>   errors on the object.

**In you migration file:**

```
def change
  create_table "apis", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "coname"
 end
 add_index :name, :status, unique: true
end
```

**And in you model:**

```
class ApiModel < ActiveRecord::Model
   validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :status }
end
```